# ECMA-262 === algorithm explanation

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand the exact algorithm for the === operator in JavaScript. It is defined as something like

> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. *If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.*
> 3. *If Type(x) is Null, return true.*
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    - If x is NaN, return false.
>    - If y is NaN, return false.
>    - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    - If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>    - If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>    - Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

Now if I write something like

```
var t1 = undefined,t2 = 2;
typeof(t1); //"undefined"
typeof(t2); //"number"

t1 === t2; //returns false ?????
```

Consider point 2 and 3: It should return true instead.
I am testing it in Chrome 15.0.874.106 m. Can somebody explain what exactly is going on in this case?

Comment: That would mean `undefined === <anything>` yields true.

Comment: The second step is only executed if both values are `undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to go in order, `If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.`.  Since false is already returned, it never gets to point 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `1:     If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.`,
`t1 === t2` should indeed return false.

`t1` is `undefined`, while `t2` is a number.